# Parallel.For is only utilising the CPU 10% all the time

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, parallel.for

So, I was trying speed up the my workflow by applying parallelism to my algorithm. I have a list of data, and I am given a window size that is less than the count of that data list.

My task is to apply a window on my data, and then I need to do some comparison to determine whether that window has bad data or not by returning a boolean. Then, I slide that window down by just 1, repeat, and continue the process until the list is finish.

The problem is it starts to get very slow when my window size is big. It will be something like O(N*W^2), where N is the data size, and W is the window size. I need to copy W size of data into a `sublist(GetRange)`, and then loop through that `sublist` to compare.

So I try to apply parallelism by putting that code in a `Parallel.For`. However, when I look at the CPU core usage it just shows ~10% utilisation, and I can see some of the cores are just being idle. How do I maximize all my CPU power in this case? I have got like 16 cores on my machine.

```
public static double CountBadData(List<double> data, int someWindowSize, double limit)
{
    var badCount = 0;
    var totalSlidings = data.Count - someWindowSize + 1;
    Parallel.For(0, totalSlidings, i =>
    {
        if (!DetermineGoodOrBad(data.GetRange(i,someWindowSize), limit))
            Interlocked.Increment(ref badCount);
    });
    
    return badCount;
}

private bool DetermineGoodOrBad(List<double> subData, double limit)
{
    foreach(var data in subData)
    {
        if (data > limit) return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Have you benchmarked your solution to verify what is actually your bottleneck? Because it sounds like memory bandwidth is your bottleneck, and parallelism won't help you with that.

Comment: _"I need to copy W size of data"_ - I am pretty confident that's the problem. Do you _really_ need to copy? Maybe consider `ReadOnlySpan<double>` ?

Comment: @MindSwipe I didn't have time to do proper benchmarking unfortunately, but I did run diagnostic tool from Visual Studio and it seems the process memory was pretty flat during this process, never changed from the start to the end of this processing

Comment: @Fildor Guess I don't need to copy cos all I am not writing to that list. I will check it out

Comment: In fact, you probably don't even need a span. If you do not modify, operating on the same List instance should be totally fine even multithreaded, anyway. Just don't make copys.

Comment: Is this the actual code you're trying to parallelize or are you leaving out details? Especially `DetermineGoodOrBad()` looks like it does a ton of duplicate checks.

Comment: ^^ I guess the intent was to create non-overlapping "windows" while implemented is kind of a sliding window?

Comment: There is a tendency for developers to turn to parallelism before actually trying to improve the algorithm. This is usually bad since the possible gains are often much less, and you need to ensure everything is thread safe. In this case you could probably gain a huge speedup by using some kind of tree structure to store the maximum. Or by splitting the ranges so they are non-overlapping, so that you only need to check a value once at most.

Comment: ^^ I'd actually expect `data.Count( d => d > limit )` to be faster than this implementation and use less memory :D

Comment: @Fildor unfortunately this is a hard requirement for me to slide a window like this (1 by 1, with a lot of overlapping). The data is actually something collected over a period of time, and we have to compute some sort of overall probability with the given window period of time

Comment: @JonasH lol, have to regret skipping algorithm classes. The thing is I can't change the way I am sliding the window, it is a hard requirement to check for same data in different windows. I tried a sort to grab the maximum so that I don't actually have to go through the window but it turned out to be slower

Comment: Are you allowed to change the signature of the `DetermineGoodOrBad` method? Or preserving the signature is part of the requirements?

Comment: Incidentally what you have above does not count bad instances of data, it counts the number of test ranges that have at least one instance of bad data in them.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes, I can change the signature however I want

Comment: @500-InternalServerError exactly, sorry bad naming lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not going to try to answer why the parallelism works poorly. There might be bandwith or caching issues, or that the CPUs spend time transferring ownership of the `badCount` variable. You will likely need to profile your program to get a real answer.

I'm instead going to try answering the implied question, how to make the code faster.

One way to do this is to keep track of how many bad values exist within the sliding window, so when we move the window one step we only need to check the values that where added and removed from the window, and decriment/increment the running count accordingly:

```
public static double CountBadData(List<double> data, int someWindowSize, double limit)
{
    var badValuesInWindow = 0;
    var totalSlidings = data.Count - someWindowSize + 1;
    var runningBadCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < someWindowSize; i++)
    {
        if (data[i] > limit)
        {
            runningBadCount++;
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < totalSlidings; i++)
    {
        if (data[i] > limit)
        {
            runningBadCount--;
        }
        if (data[i + someWindowSize] > limit)
        {
            runningBadCount++;
        }
        if (runningBadCount > 0)
        {
            badValuesInWindow++;
        }
    }
    return badValuesInWindow;
}
```

Be aware that this code is not tested. I would assume that there are a few of-by-one errors.

Comment: Needed to do a little tweak, but thank you, this is brilliant, making it just O(N)!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [JonasH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75580979/11178549) that optimizing the algorithm is a more promising path for solving your problem, than trying to parallelize an unoptimized algorithm. For the sake of completeness, the parallelization attempt could be improved by avoiding to create physical slices of the `List<double> data` with the [`List<T>.GetRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.getrange) method, and instead passing the whole list with indexes denoting the beginning and end of a virtual slice:

```
private bool IsGoodData(List<double> data, int from, int toExclusive, double limit)
{
    for (int i = from; i < toExclusive; i++)
        if (data[i] > limit) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Then the `CountBadData` can be implemented like this:

```
public double CountBadData(List<double> data, int windowSize, double limit)
{
    var badCount = 0;
    var totalSlidings = data.Count - windowSize + 1;
    ParallelOptions options = new() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount };
    Parallel.For(0, totalSlidings, options, i =>
    {
        if (!IsGoodData(data, i, i + windowSize, limit))
            Interlocked.Increment(ref badCount);
    });
    return badCount;
}
```

It is assumed that the `IsGoodData` method is restricted to just reading the `data` list. Otherwise, modifying the same `List<T>` from multiple threads concurrently would result in undefined behavior.